# A shared_ptr<my_class> object will not be accepted as a myclass method argument in a pure virtual base class

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, shared-ptr, circular-dependency, pure-virtual

I am trying to declare a method in a pure virtual class

```
class myclass
{
   virtual void mymethod(const myclass_vector & arg);
   virtual void abstract_method() = 0;
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<myclass> myclass_p;
typedef std::vector<myclass_p> myclass_vector;
```

I am unable to resolve the circularity using the methods typically used in C++. The errors I get, depending on how I forward declare the classes and the typedefs (I have also tried to convert these to class definitions) are, for example, '*field myclass_vector_instance has incomplete type myclass_vector*', also '*conflicting declaration*' errors, and linking erros.

For example,

```
class myclass;
typedef std::shared_ptr<myclass> myclass_p;
typedef std::vector<myclass_p> myclass_vector;

class myclass
{
   virtual void mymethod(const myclass_vector & arg);
   virtual void abstract_method() = 0;
};
```

will not work.

My guess is that 'std::shared_ptr' needs to know in advance the size of the object it will point to.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Works for me.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a6375c3a860b3bc3)

Comment: @JamesRootL you should have posted that code as an answer.

Comment: Posting a copy of OP's code as an answer would be good for teh lulz, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have done forward declaration of the class .Your example should work .
For example , below example is working

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <string>
#include<memory>
using namespace std;
class myclass; //forward declaration 
typedef std::shared_ptr<myclass> myclass_p;
typedef std::vector<myclass_p> myclass_vector;

class myclass
{
   virtual void mymethod(const myclass_vector & arg);
   virtual void abstract_method() = 0;
};
int main()
{
    myclass_p A;
}
```

Make sure you have all headers in place .shared_ptr is defined in "include " .It should work correctly .Let me know exact error you are facing ?

Comment: Sorry , i missed "memory" .shared_ptr is defined in "include<memory>" .

Comment: It works now, thanks! The error came from missing headers and from the linker for not having defined abstract_method(). Thank you for the example :D